# Какими простыми способами можно сверстать этот блок

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать на CSS. Буду благодарен за помощь!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `flex` для формирования колонок, каждая колонка сверху содержит шапке в которой есть нижняя граница (это даст горизонтальную линию) и `<div>1...3</div>`, отрисовываемый в виде круга и немного смещённый чтобы наложиться на границу - например так

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, как по мне.

```css
.workflow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  counter-reset: workflow;
}

.workflow__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  counter-increment: workflow;
}

.workflow__item-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.workflow__item-top::before {
  content: counter(workflow, upper-roman);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.workflow__item-top::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.workflow__item-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.workflow__item--end {
  width: auto;
}

.workflow__item--end .workflow__item-top {
  position: relative;
}

.workflow__item--end .workflow__item-top::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
}

.workflow__item--end .workflow__item-top::after {
  width: 16px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="workflow">
  <div class="workflow__item">
    <div class="workflow__item-top"></div>
    <div class="workflow__item-title">HEADLINE</div>
    <div class="workflow__item-text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="workflow__item">
    <div class="workflow__item-top"></div>
    <div class="workflow__item-title">HEADLINE</div>
    <div class="workflow__item-text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="workflow__item">
    <div class="workflow__item-top"></div>
    <div class="workflow__item-title">HEADLINE</div>
    <div class="workflow__item-text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="workflow__item workflow__item--end">
    <div class="workflow__item-top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```